# JQuery throwing Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

Seemingly out of nowhere, I'm getting an error thrown on every button click action.

This is the error;

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>
> jquery-2.0.2.min.js:5
>
> x.event.dispatch
>
> y.handle

Here is the HTML;

```
<script id="make-your-bet-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="joinGameWrapper">
        <div id="betSummary"></div>
        <div class="info">
            <label for="inputEachBet">How much will you bet?</label>
            <input id="inputEachBet" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="info buttons">
            <button id="btnSendBet" class="btn">Commit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the JS (the console.log isn't rending either so I feel like the issue might be here);

```
onSendBet: function () {
   var data = {
       eachBet : $('#inputEachBet').val() || 'anon'
   };

   IO.socket.emit('playerSentBet', data);

   App.myRole = 'Player';
   App.myBid = data.eachBet;
   console.log('hello');
},
```

Binding the buttons to functions;

```
    bindEvents: function () {
        // Host
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnCreateGame', App.Host.onCreateClick);
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnPlaceBet', App.Host.onPlaceBetClick);
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnLockGame', App.Host.onLockGame);

        // Player
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnJoinGame', App.Player.onJoinClick);
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnStart',App.Player.onPlayerStartClick);
        App.$doc.on('click', '.btnAnswer',App.Player.onPlayerAnswerClick);
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnPlayerRestart', App.Player.onPlayerRestart);
        App.$doc.on('click', '#btnSendBet', App.Player.onSendBet);
    },
```

Comment: is the error being thrown in the onSendBet function or before it? How do you trigger the onSendBet function?

Comment: The error is being thrown on all buttons, for clarity I have updated the post to display how the buttons are binded.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. The button breaking it all was #btnSendBet. This was assigned to App.Player.onSendBet, however it needed to be assigned to the host. Updating this has resolved all issues.